# Unable to get value of the property 'h': object is null or undefined

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-5.0

Trying to debug a Silverlight 5 app in Internet Explorer 9 from VisualStudio 2010 (as soon as I start debugging SL5 from vs2010), I'm getting this error :

```
Unable to get value of the property 'h': object is null or undefined.
```

My question is: the App.xaml.cs constructor has the debugging stop red dot, the error pops first then reaches this debugging point, what is being executed before?

In VS2010 I click Debug > Start Debugging then I get the error window "Webpage Error" as tittle, the red x Do you want to debug this webpage? bla,bla, on the white area is the 
Line: 13 Error: Unable to get value of the property 'h': object is null or undefined.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

to fix the error by the way...you can try to logout from the running page on IE.  (just go to upper right corner click on the name signed in as and (from the drop menu) click logout.
What happened is that I log to gmail and click on the "stay signed in". if I sign back in on the running page the error pops again.

Still would like to know the answer to my question,tho.